# How to transform a grid to 1 column in a dataframe and make it performant

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform a grid of 280*320 cells which is loaded in a dataframe.

I can do this kind of transformation on a small scale(shown in code below). But when I use this same code on 280*320 grid it takes a long time(several minutes).

Is there a way to make this more performant?

The grid contains values. The grid represents a geographical grid. Basically 280 KM by 320 KM where every cell represents 1km*km where pollution is measured.
I want to transform this grid to 1 column, so 280*320=89600 lines.
Each line should contain the value of 1 cell in the grid.
Next to that I will add 2 additional columns to represent latitude and longitude.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0],[10.0,11.0,12.0]]))

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
k = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        df1.loc[k,'pm25'] = df.iat[i,j]
        df1.loc[k,'lat'] =  df.iat[i,j] * 10   # This will be replaced by a geo conversion for latitude
        df1.loc[k,'long'] =  df.iat[i,j] * 100 # This will be replaced by a geo conversion for longitude
        k = k + 1
df1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do a [`ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to return a flattened array and assign this to the new df:

```
a=df.values.ravel() #df.values.flatten()
df1=pd.DataFrame({'pm25':a,'lat':a*10,'long':a*100})
```

Or:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df1=df1.assign(pm25=a,lat=a*10,long=a*100)
```

---

```
    pm25    lat    long
0    1.0   10.0   100.0
1    2.0   20.0   200.0
2    3.0   30.0   300.0
3    4.0   40.0   400.0
4    5.0   50.0   500.0
5    6.0   60.0   600.0
6    7.0   70.0   700.0
7    8.0   80.0   800.0
8    9.0   90.0   900.0
9   10.0  100.0  1000.0
10  11.0  110.0  1100.0
11  12.0  120.0  1200.0
```

Comment: This really speeds up processing.
Just transforming (without doing the latitude+longitude conversion) goes from 5 minutes to less than a second.
Then doing the conversion on the single column only takes 25 seconds.

For me this is more than sufficient at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.array.reshape()` to transform the array of values to a one-dimensional array.

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np

array_ = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [10.0,11.0,12.0]])
array = array_.reshape(-1,1)
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['pm25'])
df
```

[image]

you can then apply a function representing your 'geometrical conversion' to this column with `df.apply()` to get the latitudes and longitudes. Of course, if it is really just a case of multiplying by a fixed number as in your example, you can do `df['lat'] = 10*df['pm25']` and similarly for `'long'`, however `df.apply()` will allow you to apply a more general function. All the above will be fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure if this is also useful when you have a dataframe instead of an array like I showed in my example.
Nevertheless it is good to know this option

Comment: Well, you had an array in your example, which I literally copied. If you don't have the array to begin with, you would simply use df.values, which gives you the array.